# Unselect Window on Mission Control with Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, applescript, mission-control

This is an Example of Selected Mission Control Window. Safari is Selected
[image: This is an Example of Selected Mission Control Window. Safari is Selected]

And this is an example of no windows selected on mission control
[image: without selected window on mission control]

How it's possible unselect this window?

Using Swift/Obj-C/Applescript or whatever. But without changing the mouse location

My progress is this, I reached to the attribute AXSelectedChildren of Mission Control windows. Code Below

```swift
for entry in  (CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption.optionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID) as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
    {
        if entry[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as! String == "Dock"
        {
            let bounds: NSDictionary = entry[kCGWindowBounds as String] as! NSDictionary

            if (bounds["Y"] as! NSNumber) != 0{ //if Mission Control is Launched

                let dockAppElement = AXUIElementCreateApplication((entry[kCGWindowOwnerPID as String] as? Int32)!)

                var dockAttributeValues: AnyObject?

                _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(dockAppElement, kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &dockAttributeValues)

                var childrenRef = (dockAttributeValues as! [AXUIElement]).last // group 1 of Dock
                _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(childrenRef!, kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &dockAttributeValues)

                childrenRef = (dockAttributeValues as! [AXUIElement]).first // group 1 of group 1 of Dock
                _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(childrenRef!, kAXChildrenAttribute as CFString, &dockAttributeValues)

                childrenRef = (dockAttributeValues as! [AXUIElement]).first // group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of Dock
                _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(childrenRef!, kAXSelectedChildrenAttribute as CFString, &dockAttributeValues)
                        
                if let selectedWindow = (dockAttributeValues as! [AXUIElement]).first{ // selected Children of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of Dock
                    _ = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(selectedWindow, kAXTitleAttribute as CFString, &dockAttributeValues)
                    if let titleWindow = (dockAttributeValues as? String){print(titleWindow)}

                }
                else{ // if selectedChildren == nil
                    print("no windows selected")
                }
                break
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Where are you writing code?

Comment: I have a Project in Xcode, using https://github.com/soffes/HotKey to trigger actions like this. My project only need access to accessibility. I launch Mission Control and run this code with Hotkey

Comment: Is `selectedChildren` `nil`? Is `kAXSelectedAttribute` of the window `true`? Have you tried setting it to `false`?

Comment: The selectedChildren of List is = selectedWindow. The selectedWindow don't have kAXSelectedAttribute, only have kAXEnabledAttribute, and this is not settable. The attribute kAXSelectedChildren of list that contains all children windows, too is not settable.